# Question about fundamental philosophical standpoints

Tags: introduction-to-philosophy

I just started learning Philosophy.

One of my colleagues said that there are 4 fundamental philosophical standpoints:

1. Atheism
2. Agnosticism
3. Deism
4. Theism

But when I tried to read/search about the fundamental philosophical standpoints I couldn't find anything to support this statement.

From my understanding; Atheism, Agnosticism, Deism and Theism are about God/Religion. It's also hard for me to understand what one might mean by "fundamental philosophical standpoints."

Can you please guide me toward the reading material or explain it?

Thanks

Comment: Correct: there are many traditional and useful dichotomies: Rationalism/Empiricism, Platonism/Aristotelianism, etc.

Comment: Philosophy is a land of many subjects, and on each there are "fundamental philosophical standpoints". The ones named by your colleague only concern the subject of (monotheistic) God. Perhaps you should start with standpoints on the more central subjects, like metaphysics where we have materialism/idealism/dualism and epistemology where we have rationalism/empiricism/skepticism, and even those cover only some aspects of each subject.

Comment: I would add that those four positions also do not come close to exhausting the basic standpoints in philosophy of religion. For example, one of the most prominent philosopher's of religion in the 20th Century, John Hick, articulates a philosophy of religious pluralism that doesn't fall into that schema. His position is not exactly theist because he allows that the religious centre may be something which is not God-like, nevertheless it is not atheist either since the religious center may be both God-like and real.

Comment: Also adding to Conifold's comment, note that philosophy is highly opinionated; there are many ways historians of philosophy define the central standpoints of a subject. In order to not get too confused by this, I'd recommend sticking to one historian/site and taking up the definitions from them. E.g. Bryan Magee's The Great Philosophers, Anthony Kenny's A New History of Western Philosophy, Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy (SEP) articles, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with you that the four standpoints from your question do not cover the whole domain of philosophy. At best, they describe different views onto the issue whether there are gods. Hence they all four belong to philosophy of religion.

As @Conifold writes there are different schemes to classify the domain of philosophy, e.g., concerning European and Western philosophy

1. According to subdisciplines:

- Ontology (Aristotle: Metaphysics)
- Epistemology (Immanuel Kant: Critique of Pure Reason)
- Ethics (John L. Mackie: Inventing Right and Wrong)
- Political Philosophy (John  Rawls: A Theory of Justice)

2. According to positions:

- Rationalism (Leibniz)
- Empiricism (Hume)
- Transcendental philosophy (Kant)
- Existentialism (Heidegger)
- Critical Rationalism (Popper)

For Asian philosophy one has to design a separate scheme.